# Optimizing the Query with multiple unions and different counts based on conditions

Tags: sql, query-optimization, case

I have this query with multiple unions:

```
select count(emp.emp_id) "No.of emp with sal above 30k" from emp,dept
where emp.emp_sal > 30000
and emp.emp_id=dept.emp_id
union
select count(emp.emp_id) "No.of emp with age above 50" from emp
where emp.emp_age < 50
and emp.emp_id=dept.emp_id
union 
select count(emp.emp_id) "No.of emp doing over time" from emp
where emp.work_time > 10
and emp.emp_id=dept.emp_id`
```

I want to combine the above query into single query like below:

```
Select emp_id,emp_name,
case
when emp.emp_sal > 30000 then 1
when emp.emp_age < 50 then 2
when emp.work_time > 10 then 3
end 
from emp,dept
where emp.emp_id=dept.emp_id`
```

How can I include the count of the emp_id in the case statement?
I want to see all the employee counts separately.

**Sample output** will be:

```
"No.of emp with sal above 30k"   200
"No.of emp with age above 50"    100
"No.of emp doing over time"      50
```

The above count for employees are varying when i wrote as single select.
Now i used different tables for one more join. For example

```
select count(p_id) "Sold Prod" from prod,sale 
where prod.p_id=sale.p_id and sale.p_name='SAMSUNG'
union
select count(p_id) "Prod Ordered" from prod, order
where order.p_id=prod.p_id and order.order_dt > '01-Jan-2013'
```

The above join when i wrote as single select query for "sold Prod" the result is same whereas the "prod_ordered" is increased,because of the ordered id is present also in sale table. Can anyone give some idea how to retain the same numb by writing within single select?

Answer (score 1):

In your SELECT statement you could count based on the CASE like so:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN emp.emp_sal > 30000 THEN 1 Else 0 End) AS EmpSalary30000, 
SUM(CASE WHEN emp.emp_age < 50 THEN 1 Else 0 End) AS EmpAgeLess50, 
SUM(CASE WHEN emp.work_time > 10 THEN 1 Else 0 End) AS EmpWorkTimeGreat10
```

Comment: **@Gordon Linoff**, thanks for the edit.  You are right it should have been SUM.